# post file in ajax Not working in yii2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2, yii2-basic-app

In my view :

Form Field :

```
 echo $form->field($model, '['.$form_id.']['.$form_component.']c_data')->fileInput(['style' => 'color:black','data-admin'=>$admin_id,'data-form'=>$form_id,'date-component'=>$form_component,'data-unic'=>$unic_id,'data-label'=>$label,'data-user'=>$user_id,'data-required'=>$required,'data-comp_type'=>'9'])->label($label) ;
```

In same view  page script for my button click function  :

```
 var site_url = '<?php echo Url::to (['formdata/movefile','id'=>'']); ?>' + unic ;

   var form = $(this).attr("data-form");
            var component = $(this).attr("date-component");
             var file_data = $('#formdata-'+ form + '-' + component + '-c_data').prop('files')[0];
                  var form_data = new FormData();                  
                  form_data.append('file', file_data);

                   $.ajax({
                url: site_url, // point to server-side PHP script 
                dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,                         
                type: 'post',
                success: function(php_script_response){

                }
     });
```

In my controller :

```
 public function actionMovefile($id) {

                    $id= $id;


                $fileInfo = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$ipath = "download/". $id . '.' .$_FILES["file"]["name"] ;


                if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
    }
    else {

       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $ipath);

    }


              }
```

There is no error in script and file..but my upload file wasnot saved in folder

I already check the path of my folder,
I create a download folder in basic->download

I am using basic template of yii2

please anyone help me...

Comment: why don't you pass the form to the FormData and use the file property?

Comment: @madalin ivascu  No... my requirement is just take a one file field in a form and just save that file into a particular folder, when a submit button clicking function

Answer (score 0):

Have you check your folder permission?

Also check `$_FILES` object by printing it.

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Sorry but i do not have enough reputation for posting comments. When i have enough reputation i surely do.

Comment: thank u... how to check the folder permission in yii2

Comment: If you are using ubuntu try ls -l directory. Here directory is your upload directory name.

Comment: how to conform the file data is post or not

Comment: You can check inside actionMovefile controller. Try to print using print_r($_FILES);exit(); Add this code at start of the function. Open firebug  look what happens using network tab in firebug.Check the response you can find what is printed in controller.